# {LL parser} how many AST for a set expression

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, ll-grammar

I'm trying to implement an LL parser.
But I'd like to know if is it possible to get many AST for a set expression.
Exemple:
-For an expression like (a + b) * (c - d) / (e + f)
with an LL parser, the only AST possible to get is:

```
                              [/]
                             /   \
                            /     \
                         [*]       [+]
                        /   \      / \
                       /     \    /   \
                     [+]     [-] [e]  [f]
                    / \      / \
                   /   \    /   \
                 [a]   [b] [c]  [d]
```

or is there an another AST possible ? So by the way, how can I know if my AST is correctly done ?
Hopeing I was enough understandable ! :)
Don't hesitate if I wasn't, I'll try to explain my question by another way, thank's

Answer (score 0):

There is no precise definition for "abstract syntax tree" (AST). The AST produced by a given application is an abstraction of the syntax tree, and might include or exclude any data which seems relevant to that application.

Basically, the AST is whatever you want to produce from a given input. Normally, you will want to remove extraneous details (in your example, that would include the parentheses and the derivation of `IDENTIFIER` from `expression`), but that is not always the case: in some languages, parentheses are semantically significant and need to be retained, for example.

If a grammar is LL(1), then every input must have at most one valid parse. Or, to put it another way, every valid input must have exactly one valid parse. Or to be more precise, every valid input must have exactly one ["leftmost derivation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Derivations_and_syntax_trees).

From any derivation you can create a syntax tree, which represents the entire
parse, including the extraneous details which you might prefer to ignore. If there is a unique leftmost derivation, then there is only possible syntax tree.

Normally, that would mean that the AST of a given is also well-determined (assuming the parser is deterministic and not buggy), but since two different parsers for the same language might have totally different syntax tree abstractions, there is no way to say that all parsers will produce the same AST.

Comment: if there's no precise definition for AST. So I suppose that there's no precise way to browse a AST ? Given there's now precise way to browse and construct AST. Should I browse an AST according to how it was build ? or should I create an AST according to how I would like to browse it ? Thanks